# Rails 3 - multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, model, associations

I have first table called **Cars** that contains the informations about color of the car, weight, price etc.

Then I have the second table, for example **Other_informations**. This table contains another informations about that car from the first table.

In the first table (**Cars**) is the name of the car. If I need to create an associations between these two tables, I can use:

### car.rb

has many :other_informations

### otherinformation.rb

belongs_to :car

In this case I have to set the name of one column in the table **Other_informations** on **car_id** and the associations will be created.
To this point is everything ok.

But now - I need just one association to add (from the table **Other_informations** to the table **Cars** - the same type of associations as the first).

I tried to do something like this:
car.rb

```
has many :other_informations
```

otherinformation.rb

```
belongs_to :car
belongs_to :car2
```

And then in the view used:

```
data.car2.name_of_the_car_from_first_table**
```

But this unfortunately didn't work me... can anyone help me, please, if is something like this possible to do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question - do you want to have OtherInformation to be shared among different Cars? Like OtherInformation can belong to many different Cars?

You need some kind of many-to-many relationship then. Have a read:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

EDIT (after reading your comments):

```
belongs_to car, :class_name => "Car", :foreign_key => "to_col1"
belongs_to another_car, :class_name => "Car", :foreign_key => "to_col2"
```

That assumes that your OtherInformation has two columns in the database table: `to_col1` and `to_col2` And here is how associations should work:

```
other_info = OtherInformation.first
first_car = other_info.car
second_car = other_info.another_car
second_car_name = other_info.another_car.name
#etc...
```

Comment: I will try to explain it on the simple example: the table `Cars` have 2 columns - **id** and **name**. The table `Other_informations` have 3 columns: **id**, **col1**, **col2**. **col1** and **col2** are ID's of the cars from the table **Cars**. And now I have the statement from the table `Other_informations` => I know the ID's (2 ID's - col1 and col2) of the cars from the table **Cars** - but I don't know now, how to get both the names of the cars (from the table **Cars**).

Comment: Allright. Check the link above in my answer for the list of options you can pass for belongs_to association like :foreign_key, :class_name

Comment: ok, I am still struggling with it... I used in my car.rb `belongs_to :car, :foreign_key => "to_col2"` - **to_col2** is foreign key in my database table. And if I will try in my view to print the name of the car, I will get **undefined method `car_name' for 2:Fixnum**. What could be wrong? 
And one question yet - I used `belongs_to :car, :foreign_key => "to_col2"` - this mean I have the relation through **car** and also through **to_col2**?

Comment: Check my edit - it's easier to write a post in an answer than in a comment for me :)

Comment: Buddy, I love you!!! You solved my afternoon's nightmare. I am always struggling with associations...